# Atomic (electron) recombination via the Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction

Photon radiative transitions are often modeled from electron bound state (e.g. in an atomic potential) to the continuum (free states).  However, I've never seen the inverse process (recombination) described via the Schrodinger Equation.  My question therefore is:

Can you model electron recombination with the Schrodinger Equation?  If (as I assume) not, then what is the most straightforward way to examine transitions from the continuum back to bound states?

Comment: Why do you think that one cannot model the electron recombination with an ionized atom using the Schroedinger equation?

Comment: I've never seen it done.  Also, the Schrodinger Equation is similar to a diffusion equation with complex time - which does not have time reversal symmetry.

Comment: @freecharly It's also true that there is no spontaneous decay process - only stimulated (downward) transitioning (i.e., rabi flopping).  Maybe you could *stimulate* some small population from free states back into e.g. a ground state, but my intuition says that it would not be possible to relax the entire electron wavefunction back to the ground state once it has been ionized away.  But alas... I don't know!  I'd love to see an answer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're talking about absorption process? You can of course describe photon absorption via Schroedinger equation. But time dependent perturbation might be involved, that's to say, Feymann's golden rule.

Comment: @hys.0515 to be clear: I'm talking about transitions from positive energy (continuum) states to negative energy (eigen)states, not excited states to lower states.  This *can* be an absorption process, but is quite different than the physical situation described by Fermi's Golden Rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking in essence whether the emission of a photon due to the transition of an electron from a free, unbound high energy state to a bound low energy state of the atom can be modeled by using only the Schroedinger equation. While it is known that time-dependent perturbation theory can be used to find solution of the Schroedinger equation to calculate the transition rate of an electron from a low energy quantum state to a high energy bound or free state due to **photon absorption**, and also for **stimulated emission** of a photon with an electron transitioning from a high bound state to a low bound state in an atom, it cannot be done using Schroedinger's equation alone in the case of **spontaneous emission** of a photon when an electron makes a transition from a high (bound or unbound) state. The reason is that you need a wave function for the whole system including the quantized electromagnetic field. The latter can be represented by quantized harmonic oscillators. With this you can again use time-dependent perturbation theory and Fermi's Golden Rule to arrive at a transition rate from a high energy bound state to a low energy bound state in the atom. I have found this link to a Cambridge University lecture where you find the derivation [Radiative Transitions].[1](http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/lec19_compressed.pdf) I think that for the capture of a free electron on an atom and emission of a photon there should exist a similar model using Schroedinger's equation and the simple quantum harmonic oscillator model for the quantized electromagnetic field.

Comment: thanks.  To be clear: does this generally imply second quantization?  And also, the a, a dagger formalisms I've seen are highly abstract, and don't lend themselves to configuration space simulations as well as e.g., calculating cross sections.  Can you comment on this?

Comment: This implies "second quantization" although this is actually considered to be a misnomer. Here the link to the original 1927 paper of Dirac dealing with the subject. http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/114/767/243.full.pdf

Comment: I am not an expert in this field but I think that it should be possible to also calculate electron capture cross sections sections along the indicated lines.